# How to select <p> tag of a div tag using JSoup in android

Tags: android, html, css, jsoup

I am developing an application in android in which I am using JSoup to parse data from a website and display it in the activity. I want to select Paragraph tags of a particular div tag because there are so many div tags. This paragraph tags are in a table format. For this I am using this :

`document.select("p[style*=margin-left:56.9pt]");`

But using this, it is displaying only one paragraph tag. But actually there are 8 to 9 paragraph tags. I want to display all the tags. 
Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your html page or link to that html page or some snippet. Ideally select method of document tag actually returns an Elements object which is a List implementation underneath. Even though its is just one object, its a List object. Try iterating through it like

```
for (Element divTag : document.select("p[style*=margin-left:56.9pt]")) {
    //Your code 
}
```

That is one possibility. Other than that i suppose your html has only one `<p>` tag with `style` attribute set to `margin-left:56.9pt`. If this didnt help plase share your html code for more information.